# What the difference between addImmutable and addColumn in Hbase?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hbase

In put operation in HBase there are two type which is [addImmutable()](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html#addImmutable(byte[],%20byte[],%20byte[])) and [addColumn()](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html#addColumn(byte[],%20byte[],%20byte[])).

1. What is the difference between those two ?
2. Is immutable can be update/overwrite ?

Answer (score 3):

You can read more about this method in this JIRA: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HBASE-10024

Simply talking: `addImmutable` doens't copy passed array and take it 'as is'. Therefore, if you change content of passed byte array later(after call `addImmutable`), `Put` instance also see this changes and this is can be very unexpected for you. Instead of, `addColumn` copy passed byte array and you can safely reuse it as you wish.
`addImmutable` created for advanced use, when you need to prevent redundant array allocations.